# How to write this kind of query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a MySQL database and I want to migrate all query to Oracle and since I am not an expert in Oracle SQL I am stuck here.

I have query like this

```
ORDER BY 
   WEEK(`Date`) DESC, `Date` DESC";
```

My question is: How to write this `ORDER BY` expression in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_col,'iw','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')) DESC, date_col DESC
```

- There is no column naming format containing back ticks in Oracle, and `date` is a reserved keyword (*not allowed to use as a column name*)
- `TO_NUMBER()` is needed, since `WEEK()` function in MySQL returns a
  numeric value.